# Using ipset with src OR dst in one rule?

Tags: iptables, ipset

I am trying to write an iptables rule using ipset with one rule matching *src* or *dst* (or both). This

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set <name_of_ipset> src,dst -j DROP
```

does **not** work since it applies only if both *src* AND *dst* are in the *name_of_ipset*.

I know that I could simply double the rule via

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set <name_of_ipset> src -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set <name_of_ipset> dst -j DROP
```

but I hope that there is **something more simple**?!

Comment: I guess an answer saying "no you can't" won't work for you... Since this can be implemented with two rules, why would the authors of ipset + the iptables set match ever care to attempt to do this with one rule only? Do you have a practical case where this does matter?

Comment: Also providing the whole ruleset here could help. Using stateful rules often simplifies the ruleset, but it's not known if you're using any. Of course not knowing what's the *actual* problem doesn't help.

Comment: The thing above is the whole ruleset that applies. the "name_of_ipset" contains a list of all IPv4 bogon networks like 10.0.0.0/8 and should simply prevent a linux machine not to route these nets. Using one rule instead of two is just a thing of performance since iptables performes not very well with increasing number of rules.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do this:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set <name_of_ipset> src -m set --match-set <name_of_ipset> dst-j DROP
```